# Do I have to wrap L2 packets in mbufs? If yes, then how?

Tags: dpdk

I have L2 packets in form of byte arrays and I would like to send them to the internet using DPDK. The L2 packets are inside a secondary DPDK app and the plan is to send them to a primary DPDK app.

I thought of the following (inside the secondary app):

1. get an mbuf from the shared mempool
2. put the L2 packet inside the mbuf
3. put the mbuf on the shared ring for the primary to take

The primary DPDK will take them from the shared ring and send them using rte_tx_eth_burst()

My problem is that I am not sure if I should wrap the L2 packets in mbufs or not.
And if I should, then how could I do it?

What I got so far is this:

```
            let mut my_buffer = self.do_rte_mempool_get();
            while let Err(er) = my_buffer {
                warn!("rte_mempool_get failed, trying again.");
                my_buffer = self.do_rte_mempool_get();
                // it may fail if not enough entries are available.
            }
            warn!("rte_mempool_get success");
           
            //STEP ONE UNTIL HERE
            
            // Let's just send an empty packet for starters.
            let my_buffer = my_buffer.unwrap();

            // STEP TWO MISSING

            

            let mut res = self.do_rte_ring_enqueue(my_buffer);
            // it may fail if not enough room in the ring to enqueue
            while let Err(er) = res {
                warn!("rte_ring_enqueue failed, trying again.");
                res = self.do_rte_ring_enqueue(my_buffer);
            }
            warn!("rte_ring_enqueue success");
            
            // STEP THREE UNTIL HERE
```

This is Rust code, I created wrappers for the C bindings to DPDK.

Comment: I have marked this question as needs more focus because the title and real questions is different. I am unable to edit the question since there a lot of edit already presents. Please update the title to reflect the ask as `what are benefits of preparing MBUF in secondary application and share to primary for transmit.`

Comment: Updated question, this is closer to what I need to know. What do you think? I was not really interested in pros and cons, I wanted to know if I have to do it and how. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to send the desired packet out from the DPDK interface. Such as

1. Send the packet from Primary using rte_eth_tx_burst
2. Send the packet from Secondary using rte_eth_tx_burst
3. Sharing the packet (byte) array from secondary to primary
4. Sharing the fully constructed mbuf from secondary to primary

The actual question is `My problem is that I am not sure if I should wrap the L2 packets in mbufs or not. And if I should, then how could I do it?` and not `How to send L2 packets to the internet using DPDK?`

The answer is depending upon the use case one can either send the byte array or complete formulated mbuf from secondary to primary.

Advantage of sending Byte array to primary:

1. no need to allocate from mbuf pool for mbuf instance
2. No need to copy to the specific location of mbuf data position
3. no need to update mbuf headers

Advantage of sending mbuf primary:

1. mbuf can be simply validated and send out directly via tx_burst
2. no need to synchronize or use different tx queues.
3. secondary application can be built with minimal DPDK libraries and with no driver PMD also.

hence depending upon the actual intend the decision can be made.

Comment: Now I understand that I can send either byte array or mbuf from secondary to primary.
Could you also explain me a little bit on the "how" part?

This is what it is still not clear to me, I'll try to be brief:

1) If you want to send a packet from primary to internet, does it have to be wrapped in mbuf? (using rte_eth_tx_burst is the only way I know of)

2) If you want to send a packet from secondary to primary without the use of mbufs, then you have to do it without dpdk libraries? If yes, then it's not that appealing to use because that means I would have to do the IPC code by myself.

Comment: 3) How can I actually wrap an L2 packet inside an mbuf if all I know about said packet is an array of raw bytes? I am looking at the rte_mbuf struct here:
https://doc.dpdk.org/api/structrte__mbuf.html
It's overwhleming and I got two issues: I don't know how to extract needed information from my raw bytes array and I don't know which are the fields of the mbuf that need to be filled in order to at least get this working. (like which are the mandatory fields which need to be filled)

Question one and three seem of more interest to me. Thank you!

Comment: @Mihai thanks for your understanding, for helping you on how to do it. Please open a new ticket with primary and secondary code snippet. on the exact issue to understand your problem.